# How do I store information in a .dat file

Tags: linux, bash, fedora20

I have been struggling to read information and store it into a .dat file, but everytime I run my bash script it seems to run ok but the .dat file I have made is empty.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter student's name:"
read student
echo "$student"
((count = 0))

while read students[$count] ; do
((count++))
done < sorted.dat
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I would remove `((count = 0))` and simply use `students=( $(<sorted.dat) )` to fill the `students` array rather than a loop (you can also use `readarray` or `mapfile` as well). You should post a few lines of `sorted.dat` so we can see the format (and confirm how you should fill `students`). Your question is also unclear as to what you mean by *"store it into a .dat file"*, please elaborate.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do? The answerers are currently guessing.

Comment: Your observation is quite astute `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to store student in the file?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter student's name:"
read student
echo "$student" >> sorted.dat
((count = 0))

while read students[$count] ; do
((count++))
done < sorted.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

**.dat file is like a simple text file you can read and write in a normal way**

```
echo "Today's date is" date >> stored.dat
date >> stored.dat
cat stored.dat
```